# Editar un formulario en laravel

Tags: laravel, mvc, formularios

Alguien me puede ayudar, no me carga los datos a la vista de editar en laravel.

Estoy haciendo una consulta para que sepa cual registro editar..

He visto que muchas veces se hace esto:

```
 $asignacion=C_materia::find($id);  
 $id  = $asignacion->idc_materia;
```

y yo intento hacerlo con esto:

```
  $idkalificacion = DB::table('k_calificaciones')
        ->join('k_alumnos', 'k_calificaciones.idk_alumno', '=', 'k_alumnos.idk_alumno')
        ->join('c_materias', 'k_calificaciones.idc_materia', '=', 'c_materias.idc_materia')
        ->select('k_calificaciones.*','k_calificaciones.id','k_calificaciones.primera_cal','k_calificaciones.segunda_cal','k_calificaciones.ps_cal','k_calificaciones.tercera_cal','k_calificaciones.prom_cal','k_calificaciones.fecha_curso','k_calificaciones.tipo_de_aprob')
        ->where('c_materias.idc_materia', '=', $id)->where('k_alumnos.idk_alumno','=', $id2)->get();
```

Las variables $id y $id2 las recibo y con esas hago la comparación

No me marca error, pero no me muestra los datos.

en la vista hago esto:

```
   <td>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('primera_cal') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">

                            <input id="primera_cal" type="input" class="form-control" name="primera_cal" value="{{$idkalificacion->primera_cal}}">

                                @if ($errors->has('primera_cal'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('primera_cal') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div> 
                            <br>
                        </div>

                    </td>
```

Los jalo en una tabla los datos..
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: haz un dd($idkalificacion); y da un poco mas de informacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos, creo tener la solución, al hacer `->get()` estas obteniendo un array como resultado y tu utilizas a `$idkalificacion` como objeto en: `$idkalificacion->primera_cal`.

Lo que deberías hacer es llamar a `first()` en cuenta de `get()`  y ya funcionaria. O llamar de esta forma a tu parámetro :  `$idkalificacion[0]->primera_cal`  para que no tengas problemas.

Comment: Gracias , por la ayuda!